# phone format is deleted on edittext in android

Tags: android

Hı guys.I have a quetions about edittext.I have created a phone  format on edittext.

When i run the app,it is working but when i delete the numbers on edittext,format is deleted.Do you have any idea what can i do??

my image : http://hizliresim.com/knd71v

My code is :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements KeyEvent.Callback {

   EditText edittext1;
   String befor="0 _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _";
   TextView textview;
   int u,u1,u2,u3,u4,u5,a,u6,u7 ;
   String store;


@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    edittext1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    edittext1.setText(befor);
    edittext1.setSelection(1);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    //System.out.println(edittext1.length());


    edittext1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);



}

private final  TextWatcher textWatcher=new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


        if (edittext1.length() == 24) {

            String ilk=s.toString();
            edittext1.setText(ilk.substring(0, 2) + "_ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _");
            edittext1.setSelection(2);
             a=1;
        } else if (edittext1.length() == 22 && a==1) {

             store = s.toString();
             edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 4) + " - _ _ _ _ _ _ _");
             edittext1.setSelection(3);
             u=4;



        } else if (edittext1.length() == 21 && u ==4 ) {

            store = s.toString();
            u=5;
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0,4) + " - _ _ _ _ _ _ _");
            edittext1.setSelection(6);
            u1=3;


        }
        else if (edittext1.length()==21 && u1==3) {
             store = s.toString();
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 6)+" " + store.substring(6,7) + "_ _ _ _ _ _");
            edittext1.setSelection(8);

            u2=1;
        }
        else if (edittext1.length()==20 && u2==1) {
             store = s.toString();
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 9) + "_ _ _ _ _");
            edittext1.setSelection(9);

            u3=1;
        }
        else if (edittext1.length()==19 && u3==1)
        {
            String store = s.toString();
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 10) + "_ _ _ _");
            edittext1.setSelection(10);
            u4=1;
        }
        else if (edittext1.length()==18 && u4==1)
        {
             store = s.toString();
            u4=0;
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 10)+" " + store.substring(10,11) + "_ _ _");
            edittext1.setSelection(12);
            u5=1;


        }


        else if (edittext1.length()==18 && u5==1)
        {
             store = s.toString();
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 13) + "_ _");
            edittext1.setSelection(13);
            u6=1;

        }


        else if (edittext1.length()==17 && u6==1)
        {
            String store = s.toString();
            u6=2;
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 13)+ " " + store.substring(13,14) + "_");
            edittext1.setSelection(15);
            u7=1;

        }

        else if (edittext1.length() == 17 && u7 == 1) {
            String store = s.toString();
            edittext1.setText(store.substring(0, 16) + "");
            edittext1.setSelection(16);
            }

        }
     };


    }
```

Comment: you should try PhoneNumberUtils class and its format method.

Comment: http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52c5d288da0a63b7aea97c82/android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher?tag=coyote

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you utilise Android's very own `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher`. When the user types the numbers into your `EditText`, it will automatically format them in the phone number style that you are looking for.

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

The `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher` uses this method in the background:

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(Editable text, int formattingType);
```

The formatting type is automatically received from the user's phone whilst constructing the `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher`, this means that the phone number formatting will always be correct to the user's country. You can see from the Google source code:

```
public PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher() {
    this(Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
}
```

If you wanted to specify a specific format for all users, then you can simply use the second constructor:

```
public PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(String countryCode) {
    if (countryCode == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    mFormatter = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().getAsYouTypeFormatter(countryCode);
}
```

This utilises your specified country code and therefore when adding the `TextChangedListener`, you would specify in the constructor:

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher(COUNTRY_CODE));
```

However `PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher` also has specifics that can be seen in this list below:

```
int   FORMAT_JAPAN     Japanese formatting
int   FORMAT_NANP      NANP formatting
int   FORMAT_UNKNOWN   The current locale is unknown, look for a country code or don't format
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html

Comment: can i change the format that PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcer uses.

Comment: I have researched more and confirmed that it will update depending on user's current country. I have updated my answer again.

Comment: @kemal If my answer helped you fix your problem, please consider accepting it. Thanks!